# Issue with Matching Order IDs in TradingView's Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

### Update:

I managed to simplify this so I can paste a whole snippet to reproduce this problem.  This script, when run on ETHUSDT.P for Binance in Trading View Strategy Tester using the 15 minute chart (important because the timestamps will fail otherwise):

```
//@version=5
strategy("Multiple Positions Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2)

if timestamp("2023-06-10T11:00:00-07:00") <= time_close and time_close < timestamp("2023-06-10T11:15:00-07:00")
    strategy.entry('id1', strategy.long, 1)
if timestamp("2023-06-10T11:00:00-07:00") <= time_close and time_close < timestamp("2023-06-10T11:15:00-07:00")
    strategy.exit('id1', 'id1', limit = 1763)
if timestamp("2023-06-11T09:00:00-07:00") <= time_close and time_close < timestamp("2023-06-11T09:15:00-07:00")
    strategy.entry('id2', strategy.long, 1)
if timestamp("2023-06-11T09:00:00-07:00") <= time_close and time_close < timestamp("2023-06-11T09:15:00-07:00")
    strategy.exit('id2', 'id2', limit = 1751)
```

Will cause the following to show in the List of Trades tab:

| Trade # | Type | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Exit Long | id1 |
|  | Entry Long | id2 |
| 1 | Exit Long | id2 |
|  | Entry Long | id1 |

Even though both trades are wins, the strategy tester will show that the first trade is a loss (-0.48%) and the second is a larger win (1.31%) than I believe it was. This can especially affect drawdown unfairly, so it's a problem even if the overall PnL might be accurate.

## Previous question:

I am experiencing an issue with pinescript in trading view's strategy tester where my trades are getting mixed up due to order ids not matching as expected. Here's the "list of trades"

```
Trade #1
Type: Entry Long
Signal: Long Trade 770
Type: Exit Long
Signal: Exit Long 772

Trade #2:
Type: Entry Long
Signal: Long Trade 772
Type: Exit Long
Signal: Exit Long 787

Trade #3:
Type: Entry Long
Signal: Long Trade 787
Type: Exit Long
Signal: Open
```

note that the trades should actually occur in the order (and this is reflected in the strategy tester overview):

```
Enter long #770
Enter long #772
Exit long #772
Enter long #778
Exit long #778
(#770 never exits because limit is never reached)
```

My understanding is that the entry and exit ids should match for each trade. However, as seen above, the exit for trade #1 has the same id as the entry for trade #2, which seems to be causing some confusion.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title = 'My Signal', shorttitle='MY_MAIN', overlay=true, max_bars_back=300,max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, pyramiding=5000)

...

if (bar_index == 787 or bar_index == 770 or bar_index == 772)
    if (myCondition) // Defined above this snippet
        candleHigh := open
        exitLongLine := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=candleHigh, x2=bar_index+1, y2=candleHigh, color=color.red, width = 1)
        strategy.entry("Long Trade " + str.tostring(bar_index), strategy.long)
        strategy.exit("Exit Long " + str.tostring(bar_index), "Long Trade " + str.tostring(bar_index), limit=candleHigh)
```

Based on the Pine Script v5 documentation for strategy.exit() and strategy.entry(), I am under the impression that the from_entry parameter in strategy.exit() should match the id of the corresponding strategy.entry() call. However, this does not seem to be the case in my script.

While the visual appears to be correct, the net profits are incorrect (consistent with the incorrect list of trades.

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this discrepancy, and how to ensure the correct matching of trade entry and exit ids?

### Addition:

I tried a more understandable example using the first few candles which match.  The reason I'm filtering out only certain ids is because I want to simplify it for purposes of troubleshooting, but the same issue shows up when I don't filter:

Here, I filter only 19, 20, 21, and 36:

| Trade # | Type | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Exit Short | ShortTrade21 |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade32 |
| 3 | Exit Short | ShortTrade32 |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade21 |
| 2 | Exit Long | ShortTrade21 |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade20 |
| 1 | Exit Long | LongTrade20 |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade19 |

However, when I precede each entry with a

```
        strategy.close_all()
```

Then I get something more expected:

| Trade # | Type | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Exit Short | ShortTrade32 |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade32 |
| 3 | Exit Short | Close Position Order |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade21 |
| 2 | Exit Long | LongTrade20 |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade20 |
| 1 | Exit Long | Close Position Order |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade19 |

The full code looks like this:

```
bool longCondition = ...
bool shortCondition = ...

if (bar_index == 19 or bar_index == 20 or bar_index == 21 or bar_index == 32)
    if (longCondition)
        redCandleHigh := open
        trade_id := "LongTrade" + str.tostring(bar_index)
        strategy.close_all() // <-- Maybe
        strategy.entry(trade_id, strategy.long)
        strategy.exit(trade_id, trade_id, limit=candleHigh)
    else if (shortCondition)
        greenCandleLow := open
        trade_id := "ShortTrade" + str.tostring(bar_index)
        strategy.close_all() // <-- Maybe
        strategy.entry(trade_id, strategy.short)
        strategy.exit(trade_id, trade_id, limit=candleLow)

if (barstate.islast)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the two first array with your trade. Which one is the true one ? What is 'Signal : Open' ? You don't paste your entire code, we don't see how pinescript is configured, does it make the calculation on each bar only, on each tick, does it recalculate on each order filled ?

Comment: I expect the trades to be opened and closed in the same index, regardless of whether they happened later on (ie. 772 could open last week and close today, and 778 could open and close yesterday. I would expect them to show the same trading index). I did more digging. it appears that if I strategy.close_all() before each strategy.entry(), then it functions as expected.  the problem appears to be with overlapping entries.  I'll add the top of my strategy to the code, though.  The script is too large to fully include, but it is a repurposed indicator, so this is the only strategy-specific code.

Comment: Added an additional example

Comment: can you re read my first comment and questions ? You didn't answer any of them...

Comment: Regarding what the array was, I shared the list of trades from the strategy tester, exactly as it reported them.  The issue is that it appears to be closing the wrong trades and reporting losses when in reality, most were wins.  I don't know what you meant by 'the true one'.  Regarding pasting the full code, I could not because of size, but this is the important part (and I updated with the header).  Regarding when it makes the calculation, I don't know.  How can I find that out?  I assumed it made them on every bar, but maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happen with your code :

```
if (bar_index == 19 or bar_index == 20 or bar_index == 21 or bar_index == 32)
    if (longCondition)
        redCandleHigh := open
        trade_id := "LongTrade" + str.tostring(bar_index)
        strategy.close_all() // <-- Maybe
        strategy.entry(trade_id, strategy.long)
        strategy.exit(trade_id, trade_id, limit=candleHigh)
```

**You are at bar_index == 19 and your longCondition == true :**
So you will have a strategy.entry named `LongTrade19`
And a strategy.exit named `LongTrade19`
Only the strategy.entry is executed : you see Entry `Long LongTrade19`

**Then you are at bar_index == 20 and your longCondition == true :**
So you will have a strategy.entry named `LongTrade20`
And a strategy.exit named `LongTrade20`
The strategy.entry and strategy.exit are executec : you see, on the same candle your exit and entry for `LongTrade20`

In fact in your first array in your 'Addition' part, you misinterpret when your orders are executed, you should consider this :

| Trade # | Type | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Exit Short | ShortTrade32 |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade32 |
| 3 | Exit Short | ShortTrade21 |
|  | Entry Short | ShortTrade21 |
| 2 | Exit Long | LongTrade20 |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade20 |
| 1 | - | - |
|  | Entry Long | LongTrade19 |

**EDIT :**
this part of your code :

```
if (barstate.islast)
    strategy.close_all()
```

will close all your trade at each end of the bar !

Comment: But I'm sharing exactly the list of orders as was reported to me in the strategy tester.  Even though those trades are all wins, they are all reported as losses because they are closing the wrong ones.  I agree that it should be reported as you showed in your table, but that's not how it's being reported by the strategy tester, so I assumed that something was wrong with my script.

Comment: You should paste your complete code, without it, it is hard for us to reproduce the error and give you advice. Can you share also the pair you use, the timeframe and when you see such trade ?

Comment: Okay!  I managed to repro with a smaller complete script and add to the top of my question.

Answer (score 0):

add close_entries_rule="ANY" to your strategy

```
@version=5
strategy("Multiple Positions Strategy", pyramiding=2, close_entries_rule="ANY")
```

to close relative entry from